# Content Query Web Part as "latest updates", does not refresh/show all documents

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part

I'm trying to create a "Latest Update" section, that shows the latest updates on a site (new documents and presentations that are uploaded or Changed).
Right now I'm using the Content Query Web Part und it shows a few documents that are uploaded. 
However, there are a few problems:

1. The CQWB does not show if i modify an existing document, even though I used the filters to show the latest modification. If i upload a document and edit it afterwads it is displayed in the CQWB.
2. how do I manage to get a few more collumns that show the date and time when it's modified, and by who? Right now I just have the time and date when it's modified in the description, which leaves me with a lot more rows but a huge blank space on the right side..

I'm using sharepoint 2010 and I am not very experienced.. obviously.

Answer (score 3):

The CQWP certainly should do what you are looking for.  My first suggestion is to check your settings.  When I do this I usually sort by Modified date in descending order so the most recent are at the top.  I then set a maximum number of items - maybe 10 or 15 so there are not too many.

If you need to display more details then you will need to customise the XSLT which is used to present the data on the page.  I have posted a number of tutorials on generic XSLT and also how it applies to CQWP on my [blog](http://paylord.wordpress.com) so would suggest you take a look there and at the many other great resources on the topic as it is a bit too much to go into here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I made the mistake to sort by created date.